# json decode into array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to store the titles in an array and extract the long cmcontinue string from the below url.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:1980_births&format=json

my current code:

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:'.$cat.'&format=json';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "asdf");

$c = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($c);

$array = $json->{'query'}->{'categorymembers'}->{'title'};
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having? oh wait. You asked the question in perfect tune with your nickname :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try adding second paremeter of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), like:

```
$json = json_decode($c, true);
```

And get `cmcontinue` value as:

```
echo $json["query-continue"]["categorymembers"]["cmcontinue"];
```

For `titles`:

```
$titles = array();
foreach($json["query"]["categorymembers"] as $vals) {
    array_push($titles, $vals["title"]);
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($titles);
```